# Line, triangle, quadrilateral... pentagon? Or different pattern?

Tags: pattern

This is a similar puzzle to the one I asked about here: [90, 135, 180 degrees, but no 225, find the pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118258/90-135-180-degrees-but-no-225-find-the-pattern)

Say we have the following pattern.

[image]

I want to know, given the possible 4 choices, which figure should come next.

1st choice:

[image]

2nd choice:

[image]

3rd choice:

[image]

4th choice:

[image]

My thought process in approaching this problem: Notice we have a line as a divider in the 1st square, a triangle as a divider in the 2nd square, and a quadrilateral as a divider in the 3rd square. So maybe we need a pentagon as the divider as the figure that should come next, hence we should go with the 4th choice. But I'm really not sure.

Comment: Hi, may I ask if there are black and white images above, although unlikely, in your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I choose

> The 4th choice.

We can see that

> One of the lines starts at a 6 o'clock position, and goes clockwise by 90 degrees every next term of the sequence, and the other line starts at a 12 o'clock position, and goes anticlockwise by 45 degrees every next term of the sequence. Also, the white square appeared for the first and third terms in the same spot, and the black square appeared for the second and third terms in the same spot, making something like a binary sequence. Possibly in the fourth term, there should be a new symbol introduced.

> In the fourth choice, a line goes through the red square, maybe making its value zero, and there is a white diamond, possibly symbolising 4, as the white square symbolised 1 and the black square symbolised 2.

> Another thing that supports the fourth choice is your argument, but the "line" you described may be a 180 degree angle with two lines. Since a triangle has three lines and a quadrilateral has four, you can go with the pentagonal structure of the fourth choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

> Option 4

Because:

> We have two lines from the centre of the square The one that starts out pointing south goes 90 degrees clockwise in each pattern, while the one that starts pointing north goes anti-clockwise 45 degress in each pattern.
>  The only option that has the expected line positions is option 4.
>
>  I can't see any logical sequence to the black and white squares that continues in any of the four options, so am treating those as a red herring/misdirection. You could try to make up rules that would predict a red square and a diamond, but without either symbol appearing at all in the first three patterns, anything could be valid.

Comment: Nice, sorry I beat you by 7 minutes! In my answer, I think that the squares actually have meaning because of rot13(ovanel)

Comment: @CheeseCake With this sort of puzzle, you should be able to draw the next image in the sequence by spotting the patterns, without looking at the possible answers. You could guess that the white square appears in alternate images and always in the top right corner, which would mean the next image should have nothing in the top-right quadrant, but I don't see any way to predict a diamond appearing there from anything that appears in the initial sequence. And with all images so far being black/white, I can't see how one could say that the next image should contain a red square.

Comment: @flijx Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at everything I could go with

> answer 2

> The pictures are black and white - so I expect the answer to be too - but the main reason is:
>  The pictures contain 3,4,5 objects resp.:
>  2 squares and a 1 line
>  2 squares and 2 lines
>  3 squares and 2 lines
>  answer 2 is the only one that contains 6 objects, and it is black and white: It contains
>  2 long lines, 2 short lines and 2 squares.
>  (Probably, it is a bit unclear with the 2 crossing long lines)